# Session cookie with indy

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

I must browse a certain site that keeps a session id with indy's idhttp .

i use the following code to initalize the components i need.

```
procedure InitSession;
begin
  Initalized := True;
  try
  ihttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil); //the variables are declared globally
  idCookie := TIdCookieManager.Create(nil);
  ihttp.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
  ihttp.AllowCookies := true;
  ihttp.HandleRedirects := true;
  ihttp.CookieManager := idCookie;
  except
  Initalized := False;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is when i am making a request the cookie isn't sent. What do i need to do in order to send the cookie witch contains the session id. Thanks

Comment: You need to specify which Indy version you're using, as functionality has changed (sometimes dramatically) between versions. How to do things therefore can change dramatically as well.

Comment: I recommend to try the current Indy version from Subversion or the daily snapshots

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a cookie is not being sent back in new requests, then either `TIdCookieManager` rejected the cookie when it was received, or is not matching the accepted cookie to the new requests.  Can you show the actual `Set-Cookie` response header(s) that are sending cookies, and the URL(s) you think cookie(s) are not being sent back to correctly?  Did you verify that after receiving a cookie, it actually ends up in `TIdCookieManager` before sending a new request?

Which version of Indy are you using?  Prior to 2011, earlier releases of Indy 10 did have broken cookie handling that was basically unusable.  But in early 2011, `IdCookieManager.pas` and `IdCookie.pas` were complete re-written from scratch, and since May 2011 onwards have been working properly and I have not seen any new reports of cookie mishandling.

Comment: I am using Delphi XE 2 ... so when i use ihttp.Get() method the cookie should be sent automatically or i must set it manually? The cookie is recieved properly in the cookie manager. how can i do that thanks ?

Comment: i tryed this ihttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Cookie:'+idcookie.CookieCollection.Cookies[0].ClientCookie);
   but with no success

Comment: Cookies are handled automatically. Again, what does the server's `Set-Cookie` header look like that is receiving the cookie? You can get that value from the `TIdHTTP.Response.RawHeaders` property. What URL are you requesting afterwards that is not sending the cookie back? I need this info to determine if Indy is operating correctly or if this is a bug in the redesigned cookie management code.

Comment: I still need to see the **EXACT** text of the cookie's attributes (not so much the data value of the cookie) and the **EXACT** URLs being requested so I can validate Indy's cookie management. Does the problem happen on the entire deviantart website or are particular steps involved? I spent a lot of time and effort rewriting Indy's cookie logic, so I would like to find out if this is a bug or not.

Comment: Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2012 08:35:25 GMT Server: Apache Cache-Control: private P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DSP COR CURa OUR STP" Set-Cookie: userinfo=__e2372aec800df1792753%3B%7B%22username%22%3A%22%22%2C%22uniqueid%22%3A%221664abdab9f89df75c2974f5c749c813%22%2C%22hitcount%22%3A2%2C%22visitcount%22%3A2%2C%22visittime%22%3A1327912525%2C%22firstvisit%22%3A1327912525%2C%22attr%22%3A136%7D; expires=Wed, 29-Feb-2012 08:35:25 GMT; path=/; domain=.deviantart.com Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html

Comment: the problem is that when browsing categories the same images appear if i use the browser it works fine i even changed the user agent string to look like the request is made from the browser.I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I still need the URL of the page that the cookie originated from, and the URL it needs to be sent back to.  Cookies are intimately tied to URLs, and `TIdCookieManager` matches cookies by URLs. I did a quick test using `http://www.deviantart.com/` in both cases and `TIdCookieManager` accepted and returned your provided cookie OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with cookies that do not have a DOMAIN property? The IdCookie that comes with DXE2 fails to parse cookies that do NOT have a MAX-AGE property, DO have an EXPIRES property, and do NOT have a DOMAIN property. See IdCookie.pas 675 for where S seems to have an unexpected value (left over from parsing the expires property).